# Pharaohs Night call

Tags: bo

Why does the Torah tell us a second time that Pharoh Called Moshe at night the first time:

*ל*. וַיָּקָם פַּרְעֹה לַיְלָה

Then again a posuk later:

*לא*. וַיִּקְרָא לְמֹשֶׁה וּלְאַהֲרֹן לַיְלָה

What is the significance of the Night in the Second Posuk that it bears repeating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Posuk 28 it says וַיֹּאמֶר-לוֹ פַרְעֹה, לֵךְ מֵעָלָי; הִשָּׁמֶר לְךָ, אַל-תֹּסֶף רְאוֹת פָּנַי--כִּי **בְּיוֹם** רְאֹתְךָ פָנַי, תָּמוּת. The Posuk that says וַיִּקְרָא לְמֹשֶׁה וּלְאַהֲרֹן לַיְלָה was Pharoh saving face saying I am calling you as it is not daytime, it is nighttime. (Ohr Hachaim)

Answer (score 0):

The Ohr Hachaim gives another answer that since Pharoh said אַל-תֹּסֶף רְאוֹת פָּנַי and its night you cant see my face so I wont Kill you.